# Flask SQLAlchemy pool_pre_ping on MySQL not working at all

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get my head around 'MySQL server has gone away' issue. I've read [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic) article and enabled pool_pre_ping option in my Flask app config:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysqldb://user:password@localhost/test?unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
    'pool_pre_ping': True,
    'pool_recycle': 280,
    'pool_size': 100
}
```

However I'm still getting 'MySQL server has gone away' issue.

I've set wait_timeout and interactive_timeout values to 30 in MySQL server configuration and enabled MySQL general log. Now see that each request to the app starts with app makes a connection to the MySQL server. However there is no ping ("SELECT 1") issued to the server.

I've increased wait_timeout to 300 seconds and now see that each HTTP request (within timeout period) doesn't cause connections but also doesn't cause ping either. Instead first query to the MySQL is requesting the user (probably because the view function requires user to be logged in).

So I'm not sure this pool_pre_ping setting is working at all. Is it expected behavior for SQLAlchemy on MySQL?